# can we change the CSS property, width, according to the screen width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know we can write media queries. But that we can do if we need a property to change for a range of screen width. 
My question is can we set width to be a fraction of the current screen width ?

For example, width = 0.5*current size, will always set the width to half of the current width ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is can we set width to be a fraction of the current screen width

Yes, using *Viewport Units*

`1vw` = 1/100th of the width of the viewport.

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

[**Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) is IE9 and up

Answer (score 0):

for width use `vw` where `100vw` = viewport width ( the browser window width )

for height use `vh` where `100vh` = viewport height

so for what you want use `width:50wh`

for more info read here **[viewport units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `resize` event:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var current_width = $(this).width();

  var new_width = current_width * 0.5;
  $( selector ).css('width' , new_width+'%');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Things break down when you get to fractional pixels, but if your percentage values yield integer pixel value (e.g. 50.5% of 200px in the example) you'll get sensible, expected behavior.

For e.g.

```
<div id="percentage">
   <div class="first">50%=100px</div>
   <div class="second">50.5%=101px</div>
   <div class="third">51%=102px</div>
</div>
<br />  
<div id="pixels">
    <div class="first">50px</div>
    <div class="second">50.5px</div>
    <div class="third">50.6px</div>
    <div class="fourth">51px</div>
</div>

#percentage 
{
 width: 200px;
 color: white;
}

#percentage .first 
{
 width: 50%;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: red;
}

#percentage .second 
{
 width: 50.5%;
 height: 20px;
 background-color:green;
}

#percentage .third 
{
 width: 51%;
 height: 20px;
 background-color:blue;
}

#pixels 
{
 color: white;
}

#pixels .first 
{
 width: 50px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: red;
}

#pixels .second 
{
 width: 50.5px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color:green;
}

 #pixels .third 
{
 width: 50.6px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color:blue;
}

#pixels .fourth 
{
 width: 51px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use '%' of the screen width

```
somecssselector{
   width:50%;
}
```

but it won't work on some absolutely and relatively positioned elements which is nested .in that case like the above mentioned answers you must use 'vw'

Answer (score 0):

in your example just do

```
width: 50vw
```

It will always occupy 50% of the current screen. Which work even you manually resize the window, if you wanna also change the div height when screen height changed. just add:

```
height: 50vh
```

if you wanna set the div to occupy all the screen, just do.

```
{
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

for the definition of `vw` or `vh`, go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length